# Shock magnitude in IRF of vars package R

Tags: r

I am having trouble understanding the way that in R `vars` package impulse response functions are made. Namely, I am unable to find in the documentation whether the irf function takes one standard deviation as the default shock magnitude or some other value (e.g. the percentage deviation)?

For example, the Canada case in `vars` package

```
library(vars)

data(Canada)
## For VAR
var.2c <- VAR(Canada, p = 2, type = "const")
irf(var.2c, impulse = "e", response = c("prod", "rw", "U"), boot =
FALSE)
```

Is the shock in this case one standard deviation of "e" variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `irf()` function in the `{vars}` package uses the estimated standard deviation of the disturbance term for the impulse.

For your example, you can get the value by typing,

```
summary(var.2c)$varresult$e$sigma
```

This is the estimated SD of the disturbance of variable 'e' in the model 'var.2c', and it corresponds to the shock in `irf()`.

Answer (score 0):

For `VAR()` the impulse (shock) in the impulse response function is the estimated SD of the disturbance of the variable in the model.  For `SVAR()`, the shock can be specified in the A matrix (`Amat=`) or, if entered as NA in the A matrix, is specified as the estimated SD of the disturbance of the variable in the model.

As an aside, I did not expect variable order to matter for `VAR()` although order is crucial for `SVAR()`.  Is that a surprise?

```
## What is the default impulse (shock) for VAR and SVAR?
## VAR: impulse for variable j is estimated standard deviation of the disturbance term for j (or close?)
## SVAR: impulse for variable j is 1/a[j,j] in the A matrix if specified or as above if NA

library(vars)
rm(list = ls())
data(Canada)
## For VAR
var.2c <- VAR(Canada, p = 2, type = "const")
summary(var.2c)$varresult$e$sigma
summary(var.2c)$varresult$prod$sigma
summary(var.2c)$varresult$rw$sigma
summary(var.2c)$varresult$U$sigma
irf.var.2c <- irf(var.2c, boot = FALSE)
irf.var.2c$irf$e[1,"e"]
irf.var.2c$irf$prod[1,"prod"]
irf.var.2c$irf$rw[1,"rw"]
irf.var.2c$irf$U[1,"U"]

## BTW I did not expect VAR to vary by the variable ordering (but it does)
var.2c.reorder <- VAR(Canada[,c(4,3,2,1)], p = 2, type = "const")
summary(var.2c.reorder)$varresult$e$sigma
summary(var.2c.reorder)$varresult$prod$sigma
summary(var.2c.reorder)$varresult$rw$sigma
summary(var.2c.reorder)$varresult$U$sigma
irf.var.2c.reorder <- irf(var.2c.reorder, boot = FALSE)
irf.var.2c.reorder$irf$e[1,"e"]
irf.var.2c.reorder$irf$prod[1,"prod"]
irf.var.2c.reorder$irf$rw[1,"rw"]
irf.var.2c.reorder$irf$U[1,"U"]


## For SVAR (with ordering e, prod, rw, U)
a <- diag(NA,4)
a[1,1] <- 2  ## Try setting to 1, to 1/summary(var.2c.reorder)$varresult$e$sigma, etc.

## Impulse for "e" is 1/a[1,1]
## Impulse for prod, rw, U is 1/estimated standard deviation of the disturbance term

svar.2c <- SVAR(var.2c, Amat = a, max.iter=1000)
irf.svar.2c <- irf(svar.2c, boot = FALSE)
irf.svar.2c$irf$e[1,"e"]
irf.svar.2c$irf$prod[1,"prod"]
irf.svar.2c$irf$rw[1,"rw"]
irf.svar.2c$irf$U[1,"U"]
```